# Unsure of Placement of Typedef and Class

Tags: c++, class, typedef, definition

**I have been working on this program but everytime I attempt to build, I get these error messages:**

```
|41|undefined reference to `Gumball::Gumball()'
obj\Debug\main.o||In function `main':|
|24|undefined reference to `Gumball::Gumball()'
|24|undefined reference to `Gumball::Gumball()'
obj\Debug\main.o||In function `Z10eatgumballR5StackR7Gumball'
|102|undefined reference to `Gumball::Gumball()'
obj\Debug\Node.o||In function `Node':
|4|undefined reference to `Gumball::Gumball()'
|4|more undefined references to `Gumball::Gumball()' follow
||=== Build finished: 6 errors, 0 warnings ===|
```

**Im not sure what the cause of these error messages are since i have the class Gumball declared inside of my Node class and**

**`#include "Node.h"`   in my Stack class and 
`"#include "Stack.h"`  in my main. Any suggestions would be appreciated.**

my Node.h file looks like this:

```
#ifndef NODE_H
#define NODE_H

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Gumball {
    public:
        Gumball();
        string color;
        int counter;
};

typedef Gumball Type;

// Interface file  - Node class definition
class Node {
    public:
        Node();
        Type x;
        Node *n;
        Type getinfo();
        Node *getnext();
        void setinfo(Type x);
        void setnext (Node *n);
    private:
        Type info;
        Node *next;
};

#endif // NODE_H
```

and my Stack.h file looks like this:

```
#ifndef STACK_H
#define STACK_H

#include "Node.h"

typedef Gumball Type;

// Interface file  - Stack class definition
class Stack {
    public:
        Stack();
        ~Stack();
        void push(Type);
        Type pop();
        bool isempty();
        //Type size();
        void print();
    private:
        Node *top;
};

#endif // STACK_H
```

Comment: You don't need the `typedef` in `Stack.h` because it's in `Node.h`, which you're including.

Comment: Don't use `using namespace` in a header file.

Comment: without using namespace it doesn't recognize string as a type

Comment: @123 just fully qualify it then like `std::string`. Putting using directive in your header automatically pollutes the namespace of code that uses that header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where is the `Gumball::Gumball()` constructor defined? Is that in a `gumball.cpp` file? If not, then try defining it inline:

```
class Gumball {
    public:
        Gumball() {}
```

Comment: the constructor is defined in the .cpp file

Comment: Okay, is your link step including that .cpp file in the build? Basically, the error you showed is a linker error saying that the linker doesn't know where to find the definition of `Gumball::Gumball()`.

Comment: I have tried to use to inline method of defining the constructor: class Gumball {
    public:
        Gumball() {color = " ", counter = 0};
        string color;
        int counter;
}; but i get a error message saying "error: expected ';' before '}' token

Answer (score 1):

Have you implemented any of the class methods? All I see are a bunch of class declarations.